# jQuery trigger click event via a link

Tags: jquery, hyperlink

I have on one website a UL which uses the following jQuery to sort (hide or show relevant products)

```
$('ul#portfolio li').each(function() {

                if(!$(this).hasClass(filterVal)) {

                    $(this).fadeOut('slow').addClass('hidden');

                } else {

                    $(this).fadeIn('slow').removeClass('hidden');

                }

            });
```

I want to link to this page from a separate website but as the URL isn't affected I wondered if it was possible to still trigger the sorting via an external link?

For instance say one option was chocolate I'd like to link to the page and trigger the chocolate filter button on load?

Comment: Please clearly state your query? I am unable to understand whats the issue?

Comment: I press a button which shows only the products requested (chocolate) and hides the rest but as it is jQuery it doesnt affect the URL. What I want to know is if i want to link externally to that page but show only chocolate - is that possible as just linking the URL would show all products.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to make this dependent on a query in the url:

```html
http://yourhost.org?sort=chocolate
```

For this you'll have to extract the filtering in a local function:

```
var filterList = function( filterVal ) {
  $('ul#portfolio li').each( function() {
    if(!$(this).hasClass(filterVal)) {
      $(this).fadeOut('slow').addClass('hidden');
    } else {
      $(this).fadeIn('slow').removeClass('hidden');
    }
  });
});

// Now you can use filter list whenever you want:
filterList( 'strawberries' );

// E.g. depending on the query string:
// First lets parse the search string of the window location
var arrKeyVal, oQuery = {},
    arrQs = window.location.search.substring(1).split('&');
for( var i = 0; i < arrQs.length; i++ ){
   arrKeyVal = arrQs[i].split('=');
   if( arrKeyVal[0] !== '' ) {
     oQuery[ arrKeyVal[0] ] = arrKeyVal[1];
   }
}
// Now filter:
filterList( oQuery['sort'] );
```